# ¿Cómo solucionar problema con error de API?

Tags: android-studio, phpmyadmin, cpanel, panel-de-administracion

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy trabajando un source en android studio de oxoo para una aplicación de peliculas que se trabaja con un panel en un hosting y dominio, ya todo esta listo y verificado pero cuando voy a conectar la aplicación me sale un error asi! "falló la comunicación con el servidor. Por favor revise su configuración API" y la pregunta es que soy algo novato en el tema, soy autodidacta asi que estoy aprendiendo, supongo que podría ser algo en la base de datos, ¿alguien ha tenido ese problema?

intente volver a crear la aplicación desde cero, me refiero a configurarla, verifique que no tuviera errores y volvi a compilar y hasta ahí todo está bien pero al conectar sale el mismo error; deduzco que el problema puede estar en el panel en la base de datos pero ahi si no se bien como proceder

Comment: Si entendí bien, la base de datos está en un sitio remoto (hosting) ¿quizá expuesta mediante una API? Dinos qué usas para interactuar con la base de datos remota (Retrofit, Volley, etc). Dinos si hay errores en tu Logcat de Android. Dinos qué depuraciones has hecho y con qué resultados.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.